# Script Play e Pause em video HTML5 não funciona

Tags: javascript, java, html5, script

Eu encontrei esse script aqui no site. ele serve para dar play e pause em videos Html 5.

Mas ele parece ter um erro, o efeito de click e pause só funciona se tiver 1 video na pagina, se tiver 2 videos o efeito só acontece no primeiro, o segundo video é necessário dar o play no botão nativo do player que fica um pouco abaixo.  alguem saberia ajeita ele, para que o efeito aconteça em todos os videos que tiver na pagina?

```
 Video 01

 <video id="videoID" preload="metadata" controls="controls" width="100%" height="100%">
  <source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   <source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video>
```

Video 02

```
 <video id="videoID" preload="metadata" controls="controls" width="100%" height="100%">
 <source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
 <source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video>


 --------------------
 Script
--------------------------------


 <script>
var v = document.getElementById('videoID');
v.addEventListener(
   'play', 
      function() { 
         v.play();
      }, 
    false);

   videoID.oncontextmenu = function(){ return false; };

v.onclick = function() {
  if (v.paused) {
    v.play();
    v.controls=true;
  } else {
    v.pause();
    v.controls="";
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Isso deve estar acontecendo porque vc tem dois id's iguais para os vídeos. Tenta mudar pra classe, trocando `<video id="videoID"...` pra `<video class="videoID"...` (faz isso nos dois) , e depois no jQuery troca o `var v = document.getElementsById('videoID)` por `var v = document.getElementsByClassName('.videoID');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a sugestão do @gustavox nos comentários, e seguindo algumas boas práticas, vamos à solução:

1. **NÃO** duplique seus `IDs`.

   Em hipótese alguma isso é boa prática. Não deve ser feito de jeito nenhum. `IDs` são referências de elementos únicos, enquanto `classes` devem ser usadas para elementos que se repetem.
2. Ajuste o seu **HTML**

   A sua marcação está estranha, com dois `source` dentro de cada tag, sugiro que você troque isso:

   ```
   <video id="videoID" preload="metadata" controls="controls" width="100%" height="100%">
    <source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video>
   ```

   Por isso (veja que os videos agora tem `class`, e não `id`s.

   ```
   <video class="meus_videos" preload="metadata" controls="controls" width="100%" height="100%">
       <source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   </video>

   <video class="meus_videos" preload="metadata" controls="controls" width="100%" height="100%">
       <source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   </video>
   ```

   Apesar do atributo `src` ser o mesmo (acredito que isto seja pra fins de desenvolvimento e que vá mudar), cada vídeo deve estar dentro da sua tag.
3. Parametrize a sua função.

   Como você vai rodar a mesma rotina em mais de um vídeo (aliás, você tem que fazer isso pra que o que você quer fazer funcione), é interessante tornar essa rotina uma função, ou seja:

   ```
   function habilitar_video(_v){
       _v.addEventListener('play', function() { 
           _v.play();
       },false);

       _v.oncontextmenu = function(){ return false; };
       _v.onclick = function() {
           if (_v.paused) {
               _v.play();
               _v.controls=true;
           }
           else {
               _v.pause();
               _v.controls="";
           }
       };        
   }
   ```

Com tudo isso pronto, basta você pegar todos os itens com a classe `meus_videos` (ou qualquer nome que eles tenham, contanto que sejam o mesmo), e itere sobre eles chamando a função que você criou, da seguinte maneira:

```
var videos = document.getElementsByClassName('meus_videos');
var i = videos.length;

while(i--){
    habilitar_video(videos[i]);
}
```

Veja tudo funcionando [aqui](http://codepen.io/caio1511/pen/RPjpoM).